# lightning-input of type "toggle" - any way to change the Inactive/Active text?

Tags: slds, lightninginput

For this component::

```
<lightning-input type="toggle" ...></lightning-input>
```

the "Inactive" and "Active" text appears to be fixed:

[image: Active and Inactive example]

Is it? Is coding this up per the [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-toggle/#Base) the only way to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) use the:

- message-toggle-active
- message-toggle-inactive

Attributes on the lightning-input itself to define the text.

Comment: Duh - thought I'd looked but obviously not. Thank-you.